# Sum of second order recurrence relation, non constant coëfficients

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

Is there a general way to calculate the sum of a second order recurrence relation with non constant coëfficients? In my case, I have
$$N_i = A_iN_{i-1} + B_iN_{i-2}.$$
Where I'm particularly interested in
$$\sum_{i=0}^m N_i$$

For my case, the problems might simplify due to the boundary conditions
$$N_0 = 1,$$
$$N_1 = 0$$
such that in principle it should be possible to write the sum als a function of all the $A$'s and $B$'s.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a general workaround that might or might not be helpful. In my case, it does speed up the calculation, so I thought I'd share it.

First, let me rewrite the recurrence relation a little:
$$
N_{i-1} = A_{i-1}N_{i-2} + B_{i-1}N_{i-3}
$$
Which can be substituted in the original expression for $N_i$:
$$
N_i = (A_iA_{i-1} + B_i)N_{i-2} + A_{i-1}B_{i-1}N_{i-3}
$$

The recurrence relation can then be written as a matrix product:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
N_{i} \\
N_{i-1}
\end{matrix}
 \right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
A_iA_{i-1} + B_i & A_{i-1}B_{i-1} \\
A_{i-1} & B_{i-1}
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
N_{i-2} \\
N_{i-3}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

We can now define $M_i$ to be the $2\times2$ matrix on the right-hand-side. Assuming the boundary conditions $N_0$ and $N_1$ are known, we have
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
N_{i} \\
N_{i-1}
\end{matrix}
 \right) = M_iM_{i-2}\dots M_1\left(\begin{matrix}
N_1 \\
N_0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Where $M_1 = I_2$.

Of course, this specific case only works for odd $i$, but can be reformulated for even $i$ just as easily. In my case, I could even rewrite the sum over $N_i$ as a sum of traces. This was due to one of the boundary conditions being zero, but I won't go into these details.

Comment: I was wondering that if we rewrote the recurrence relation in the matrix form like $(N_i~~N_{i-1})^\top = M_i(N_{i-1}~~N_{i-2})^\top$, will this form make the analysis much  harder? or just the same as you posted?

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is that the recurrence or summation problems are always harder than the equivalent differential equation or integral.  Differential equations with non-constant coefficients are generally very hard.  So recurrence relations will be that much harder.  Usually the answer depends on the specifics of the problem, and it is often a clever trick that answers it.

Comment: Does it help when $A_i$ and $B_i$ are actually continuous functions? That is, $A_i = \tilde{A}(x_i)$.

Comment: Not in my experience.